# How do I display only the 3rd level in an unordered list using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have an unordered list that's being automatically generated as such..

```
<div class="main">
   <ul class="list">
      <li class="section">
         Level 1
         <ul class="list">  
            <li class="section">
               Level 2
               <ul class="list">
                  <li class="section item">
                     Level 3
                  </li>
               </ul>
             </li>
          </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

How can I target only that 'item' class so that it displays and the preceding li's are hidden?

I would like to be able to just display

```
<div class="main">
   <ul class="list">
      <li class="section item">
         Level 3
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please be more specific and define `everything else`. You can't hide a parent and show it's child (simply) which it sounds like what you might be asking. Showing expected results always helps

Comment: You're correct. Made some edits to original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking to hide text nodes which can't be done directly, so the simplest start point would be put those text nodes in their own element with a class so the elements containing text only can be hidden

```
<div class="main">
   <ul class="list">
      <li class="section">
          <span class="label">Level 1</span>
         <ul class="list">  
            <li class="section">
                <span class="label">Level 2</span>
               <ul class="list">
                  <li class="section item">
                     <span class="label">Level 3</span>
                  </li>
               </ul>
             </li>
          </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Then you can use:

```
 $('.item').parents().children('.label').hide();
```

`parents()` traverses all the way up the DOM , then using `children()` will only target the immediate descendants ( and not any others that are deeper nested)

This solution maintains full tree structure. Manipulating tree structure itself could also be done depending on needs

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/704cwxLm/2)**</kbd>

Comment: This is simplest case... the whole tree could be stored and structure manipulated also